# How to login in wordpress using facebook credential

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to build login system using the Facebook API. I have done successfully the user registration using facebook API and then login, that I have done using the wordpress built-in function `wp_create_user` and `wp_signon` after getting facebook's user data. Now when user logged out and will try to login, I want to let the user to login using facebook credential rather than using password. `i.e. if email exist then login by email and facebook identifier or similar something`.  I have been trying to find it's solution for few days. But no luck. My code is as:

```
if( email_exists( $email ) || username_exists( $username ) ){
  // ** how to login using facebook credential rather than using password 
}
```

Comment: try to use a facebook wordpress [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/facebook)

Comment: I want to do something custom.

Comment: Download one of the fb login plugin from wordpress plugin repository and check the code base of downloaded plugin. That is the best way

Comment: there is much interesting ... I got two popular plugins that they used the function `wp_set_auth_cookie` but wordpress reference says: "When $remember is set, the cookies will be kept for 14 days or two weeks.". https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie